# Prevent typescript from accepting function return types that are never returned

Tags: typescript

How do I tell typescript to warn me when I set a function return type that will never be returned? Like in this example, I will never return a PinkUnicorn.

```
function giveNumber(): number|PinkUnicorn {
    return 42;
}
```

Comment: what if `type PinkUnicorn = 42`? Or more general `type PinkUnicorn = number | 'fluffy'`? If this is possible (and I'm not sure it should be), it's probably some flag for your `tsconfig.json`, but I don't know any more than that

Comment: what if `function giveNumber(): 24 | 42 { if (Math.random() > 1) return 42; else return 24; }`?

Comment: Another problem is in your wording, kinda: The return type _is_ `number | PinkUnicorn`, and that's returned every time. It's a Union Type...

Comment: I think the real problem here is that you can't define when a return type is "too wide". The narrowest type you can return from this function is "42". Then any combination of 42 with any other type. For example "42|24" or "42|string". Why is "number" correct but "number|PinkUnicorn" isn't? How can an algorithm decides what return type is too wide?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an option to do this using [TSConfig](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig) or [TypeScript ESLint](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/). There may be a way to create a custom rule to do this, but that's not advisable even if it is possible. Such a rule would cause problems with inheritance and could force you to introduce breaking changes into your code.

Suppose you have a module that exports a class `Foo` with a method `getNumberOrString` which returns a `number` or a `string`.

```
export class Foo {
    getNumberOrString(): number | string {
        return Math.random() === 0 ? 1 : "A";
    }
}
```

And suppose another class `Bar` extends `Foo` and overrides `getNumberOrString` to always return a `string`. The rule forces you to remove `number` from the return type, which is fine because `string` is assignable to `number | string`.

```
class Bar extends Foo {
    override getNumberOrString(): string {
        return "A";
    }
}
```

At some point in the future you make a change so that the implementation of `getNumberOrString` in `Foo` only returns a `number`. You may still want other implementations of `getNumberOrString` to be able to return a `string`, but the rule forces you to remove `string` from the return type.

```
export class Foo {
    getNumberOrString(): number {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Now the file containing `Bar` won't compile because type `string` isn't assignable to type `number`.